# "Stored PROCEDURE does not exists" error in Java based GUI for searching MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, stored-procedures, netbeans

I am trying to build a database search engine using NetBeans for a construction company in order to search for a price of an item based on previously done projects. I have all the tables migrated into a MySQL schema. The format of all the tables is something like this 
[Format of original Access tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42dmL.jpg)

I am trying to generate a query which will run through all these tables and provide a table for all the results. The sample query would be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM test.university_13 WHERE Sec LIKE "10%" AND Descrip LIKE "%Tackboard%" LIMIT 20
```

This is for only one table which is university_13. I have code that creates a tables list of all the tables and then I am looping a MySQL stored procedure which would run through each item of the created tables list and return a result set. The stored procedure is something like this:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_table`(IN tbl VARCHAR(100), IN sec VARCHAR(100), IN des VARCHAR(100))
        BEGIN
        SET @t1 = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ",tbl," WHERE Sec LIKE'",sec,"' AND Descrip LIKE'",des,"'");
        PREPARE stmt FROM @t1;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        END
```

Here is my code snippet from NetBeans:

```
private void SearchButActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        try{
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "password";

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query1 = "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema= 'test'";
        tables_list.add(stmt.executeQuery(query1));

        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }

        Update_table(con);

    }                                         
/* To create a table of results*/
    private void Update_table(Connection con) {
            CallableStatement statement;
            ResultSet rs2;
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            try{
                                for (int i=0; i<tables_list.size(); i++) 
                {

                    tbl = tables_list.get(i).toString();


                                       try{
                        statement = this.con.prepareCall("{call update_table(?, ?, ?)}");
                       statement.setString(1,tbl);
                       statement.setString(2,sec);
                       statement.setString(3,des);
                       rs2 = statement.executeQuery();

                    ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs2.getMetaData();
                    int numberOfColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();

                    while (rs2.next()){
                        int j=1;
                        while (j <= numberOfColumns) {
                            list.add(rs2.getString(j++));
                        }
                    }
                     resultTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));

                    }
                    catch(SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }

                    }

            }
            catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }

    }
```

The error I am getting right now is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use execute method to run stored procedure. `rs2 = statement.execute();` try this.

Comment: I tried that already. It gives me a warning saying, "boolean cannot be converted to ResultSet"

Comment: @amolkit statement.execute() returns a bool which shows whether the SP has results or not.